# PrimeFaces dataTable: ajax catches filter event but not sort event

Tags: ajax, sorting, events, primefaces, datatable

I am able to catch the filter event and call a function in the backing bean but using similar code I can not catch the sort event. The strange thing is that I have several pages where I do "exactly" the same and work just fine. The dataTable simply does not react to the mouse click when I try to sort by any column. The backing bean sort listener does not get called but the filter listener does.

Thanks in advance for any help.

in the code below, TemplateBasic.xhtml simply inserts "content" in an h:form

This is the xhtml: (the ajax commands are about the middle, just before the end of the dataTable)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/TemplateBasic.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <ui:define name="content">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><p:graphicImage url="#{resource['images/goldCup3small.jpg']}" height="30" /></td>
        <td><h2>#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipsStandingsTitle()}</h2></td>
        <td><p:graphicImage url="#{resource['images/goldCup3small.jpg']}" height="30" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p:dataTable id="standingsList"
                 var="item" 
                 value="#{listStandingsBean.standings}" 
                 widgetVar="standingsTable"
                 emptyMessage="#{mainBean.getListEmptyMsg()}" 
                 filteredValue="#{listStandingsBean.filteredStandings}"
                 style="white-space: pre-line; font-stretch: condensed; width: 100%; padding: 0px" 
                 scrollable="true"
                 scrollRows="20"
                 scrollHeight="250"
                 scrollWidth="90%"
                 liveScroll="false"
                 resizableColumns="true"
                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                 >

      <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
          <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.getSearchAllFieldsLabel()}" />
          <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                       onkeyup="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()" 
                       style="width:150px" 
                       placeholder="#{mainBean.getEnterKeywordPlaceholder()}"/>

          <p:commandButton actionListener="#{listStandingsBean.clickReturn()}"
                           icon="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-left"
                           title="#{mainBean.getReturnButtonTitle()}"
                           onclick="PF('dlgWait').show();"
                           ajax="true"
                           style="float: left"/>

        </p:outputPanel>
      </f:facet>

      <p:column headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getRowTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getRowTxt()}" 
                width="10" style="text-align: center">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{item.id.year}" 
                sortBy="#{item.id.year}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getYearTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getYearTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="exact" width="70" style="text-align: center; padding: 1px">
        <f:facet name="filter">
          <p:spinner size="3" value="#{listStandingsBean.currYear}"
                     onchange="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()"
                     styleClass="year-spinner" >
            <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
          </p:spinner>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id.year}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}"
                sortBy="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}"
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getUserTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getUserTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="120" style="white-space: pre-line; padding: 2px">
        <f:facet name="filter">  
          <p:inputText size="10" onkeyup="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()" /> 
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{item.id.level}" 
                sortBy="#{item.id.level}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="70" style="padding: 2px">
        <f:facet name="filter" >
          <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()">
            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"  />
            <f:selectItems value="#{listStandingsBean.levels}"  />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelName( item.id.level )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" 
                sortBy="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="130" style="white-space: pre-line; padding: 2px">
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSd+item.pointsRd}" 
                style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSd+item.pointsRd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSd}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsRd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsRd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsEd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsEd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSo}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsRo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsRo}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsEo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsEo}"/>
      </p:column>
      <p:ajax event="filter" update="contentForm:graphsAccordion"
              listener="#{listStandingsBean.filterEvent}"/>
      <p:ajax event="sort" update="contentForm:graphsAccordion"
              listener="#{listStandingsBean.sortEvent}" />
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:remoteCommand name="onCompleteAuto" oncomplete="PF('standingsTable').filter()" autoRun="true" />

    <p:accordionPanel id="graphsAccordion" 
                      widgetVar="graphsAccordion"
                      multiple="true"
                      activeIndex="-1"
                      style="width:90%" >
      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSRD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(0)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(1)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartRD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(2)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartED"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(3)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(4)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartRO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(5)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartEO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(6)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>


  </ui:define>


</ui:composition>
```

and the backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean( name = "listStandingsBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class ListStandingsBean {

  @ManagedProperty( value = "#{mainBean}" )
  private MainBean mainBean;

  private ModelForView theModel;
  private Controller theController;

  private List<Standings> standings;
  private List<Standings> filteredStandings;
  private Long index = 0L;
  private HorizontalBarChartModel horizontalBarModel[];

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of StandingsBean
   */
  public ListStandingsBean() {
    horizontalBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel[ 7 ];
  }

  public MainBean getMainBean() {
    return mainBean;
  }

  public void setMainBean( MainBean mainBean ) {
    this.mainBean = mainBean;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    theModel = mainBean.getModel();
    theController = mainBean.getController();
    index = 0L;
    standings = theModel.getStandings();
  }

  //
  // queries
  //
  public Integer getCurrYear() {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    return c.get( Calendar.YEAR );
  }

  public void setCurrYear( Integer y ) {
  }

  public void setStandings( List<Standings> standings ) {
    this.standings = standings;
  }

  public List<Standings> getStandings() {
    return standings;
  }

  public Long getIndex() {
    return ++index;
  }

  public List<Byte> getLevels() {
    Byte levels[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    return Arrays.asList( levels );
  }

  public List<Standings> getFilteredStandings() {
    index = 0L;
    return filteredStandings;
  }

  public void setFilteredStandings( List<Standings> filteredStandings ) {
    this.filteredStandings = filteredStandings;

    this.updateCharts();
  }

  /*
   * user actions
   */
  public void clickReturn() {
    theController.clickReturn( UI.LIST_STANDINGS );
  }

  public void updateCharts() {
    for( int chMode = 0; chMode < 7; chMode++ ) {

      HorizontalBarChartModel model = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
      model.setShadow( false );
      model.setZoom( false );
      model.setMouseoverHighlight( false );
//    model.setLegendCols( 4 );
      model.setAnimate( false );
      model.setMouseoverHighlight( true );
      model.setBarMargin( 0 );
      model.setBarPadding( 1 );
//    model.setLegendPlacement( LegendPlacement.OUTSIDE );
//    model.setExtender( "standingsChartExtender" );
//    model.setLegendPosition( "ne" );
      model.setShowPointLabels( true );
      model.setShowDatatip( false );
      model.getAxes()
        .put( AxisType.Y, new CategoryAxis( "Driver Level_Championship" ) );
      Axis xAxis = model.getAxis( AxisType.X );
      xAxis.setLabel( "Points" );
      xAxis.setTickAngle( 0 );

      if( filteredStandings == null || filteredStandings.size() <= 0 ){
        horizontalBarModel[chMode] = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
        continue;
      }
      Collections.reverse( filteredStandings );
      ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries();
      //series.setLabel(  );
      for( Standings s : filteredStandings ) {
        String dataLabel
               = theModel.getUserFullName(
            s.getId().getUser() )
                 + " L" + s.getId().getLevel()
                 + "_C" + s.getId().getChampionship();
        switch( chMode ) {
          case ChMode.SRD:series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSd() + s.getPointsRd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.SD: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.RD: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsRd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.ED: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsEd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.SO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSo() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.RO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsRo() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.EO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsEo() ) );
            break;
        }
      }
      model.addSeries( series );
      Collections.reverse( filteredStandings );

      horizontalBarModel[chMode] = model;
    }
  }

  public int getChartHeight() {
    return 60 + 15 * ( filteredStandings == null ? standings.size() : filteredStandings.size() );
  }

  public HorizontalBarChartModel getChartModel( int chMode ) {
    return horizontalBarModel[chMode];
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Functionality Methods
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public String getUserName( long userNumber ) {
    return theModel.getUserFullName( userNumber );
  }

  public String getChampionshipName( Standings item ) {
    return item == null ? "Unknown"
           : theModel
        .getChampionshipName(
          item.getId()
            .getLevel(),
          item.getId()
            .getChampionship()
        );
  }

  public String getLevelName( int level ) {
    String[] levelName = {
      "Planet",
      "Intl. Region",
      "Country",
      "Nat. Region",
      "State",
      "Municipality",
      "Venue",
      "Variant"
    };
    return level + " " + levelName[ level ];

  }

  private static class ChMode {

    public static final int SRD = 0;
    public static final int SD = 1;
    public static final int RD = 2;
    public static final int ED = 3;
    public static final int SO = 4;
    public static final int RO = 5;
    public static final int EO = 6;

    public ChMode() {
    }
  }

  public String getChampionshipsStandingsTitle() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "CHAMPIONSHIPS STANDINGS" );
  }

  public String getRowTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "ROW" );
  }

  public String getYearTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "YEAR" );
  }

  public String getUserTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "USER" );
  }

  public String getLevelTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "LEVEL" );
  }

  public String getChampionshipTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "CHAMPIONSHIP" );
  }

  public String getSR_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "SR DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getS_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "S DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getR_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "R DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getE_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "E DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getS_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "S OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getR_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "R OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getE_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "E OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public void sortEvent( SortEvent e ){
    e.getSortColumn();
  }

  public void filterEvent( FilterEvent e ){
    e.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for having been editing this. I was trying to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found what caused that strange behaviour.

It happens that I was updating the HorizontalBarChartModel array using the filteredStandings list but, when this list was empty, I left the model as it comes after creating it. This seems to leave the model with a null pointer somewhere because it has no series on it. This null pointer somehow corrupted something else and, very strangely, the sort event was not sent.

Just for those curious I put here the code as it worked:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/TemplateBasic.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <ui:define name="content">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><p:graphicImage url="#{resource['images/goldCup3small.jpg']}" height="30" /></td>
        <td><h2>#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipsStandingsTitle()}</h2></td>
        <td><p:graphicImage url="#{resource['images/goldCup3small.jpg']}" height="30" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p:dataTable id="standingsList"
                 var="item" 
                 value="#{listStandingsBean.standings}" 
                 widgetVar="standingsTable"
                 emptyMessage="#{mainBean.getListEmptyMsg()}" 
                 filteredValue="#{listStandingsBean.filteredStandings}"
                 style="white-space: pre-line; font-stretch: condensed; width: 100%; padding: 0px" 
                 scrollable="true"
                 scrollRows="20"
                 scrollHeight="250"
                 scrollWidth="90%"
                 liveScroll="false"
                 resizableColumns="true"
                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                 >

      <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
          <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.getSearchAllFieldsLabel()}" />
          <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                       onkeyup="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()" 
                       style="width:150px" 
                       placeholder="#{mainBean.getEnterKeywordPlaceholder()}"/>

          <p:commandButton actionListener="#{listStandingsBean.clickReturn()}"
                           icon="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-left"
                           title="#{mainBean.getReturnButtonTitle()}"
                           onclick="PF('dlgWait').show();"
                           ajax="true"
                           style="float: left"/>

        </p:outputPanel>
      </f:facet>

      <p:column headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getRowTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getRowTxt()}" 
                width="10" style="text-align: center">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{item.id.year}" 
                sortBy="#{item.id.year}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getYearTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getYearTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="exact" width="70" style="text-align: center; padding: 1px">
        <f:facet name="filter">
          <p:spinner size="3" value="#{listStandingsBean.currYear}"
                     onchange="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()"
                     styleClass="year-spinner" >
            <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
          </p:spinner>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id.year}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}"
                sortBy="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}"
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getUserTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getUserTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="120" style="white-space: pre-line; padding: 2px">
        <f:facet name="filter">  
          <p:inputText size="10" onkeyup="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()" /> 
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getUserName( item.id.user )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{item.id.level}" 
                sortBy="#{item.id.level}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="70" style="padding: 2px">
        <f:facet name="filter" >
          <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF( 'standingsTable' ).filter()">
            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"  />
            <f:selectItems value="#{listStandingsBean.levels}"  />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getLevelName( item.id.level )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column filterBy="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" 
                sortBy="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipTxt()}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains" width="130" style="white-space: pre-line; padding: 2px">
        <h:outputText value="#{listStandingsBean.getChampionshipName( item )}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSd+item.pointsRd}" 
                style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSd+item.pointsRd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSd}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsRd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsRd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsEd}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsEd}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsSo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsSo}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsRo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsRo}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column sortBy="#{item.pointsEo}" style="white-space: pre-line; text-align: right" 
                headerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}" 
                footerText="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.pointsEo}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:ajax event="filter" update="contentForm:graphsAccordion"
              listener="#{listStandingsBean.filterEvent}"/>
      <p:ajax event="sort" update="contentForm:graphsAccordion"
              listener="#{listStandingsBean.sortEvent}" />

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:remoteCommand name="onCompleteAuto" oncomplete="PF('standingsTable').filter()" autoRun="true" />

    <p:accordionPanel id="graphsAccordion" 
                      widgetVar="graphsAccordion"
                      multiple="true"
                      activeIndex="-1"
                      style="width:90%" >
      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getSR_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSRD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(0)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getS_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(1)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getR_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartRD"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(2)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getE_DriverPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartED"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(3)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getS_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartSO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(4)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getR_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartRO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(5)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>

      <p:tab title="#{listStandingsBean.getE_OwnerPointsTxt()}">
        <div align="left">
          <p:chart id="standingsChartEO"
                   type="bar" 
                   model="#{listStandingsBean.getChartModel(6)}" 
                   responsive="true"
                   style="height:#{listStandingsBean.chartHeight}px; width:80%; "
                   />
        </div>
      </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>


  </ui:define>


</ui:composition>
```

The backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean( name = "listStandingsBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class ListStandingsBean {

  @ManagedProperty( value = "#{mainBean}" )
  private MainBean mainBean;

  private ModelForView theModel;
  private Controller theController;

  private List<Standings> standings;
  private List<Standings> filteredStandings;
  private Long index = 0L;
  private HorizontalBarChartModel horizontalBarModel[];

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of StandingsBean
   */
  public ListStandingsBean() {
    horizontalBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel[ 7 ];
  }

  public MainBean getMainBean() {
    return mainBean;
  }

  public void setMainBean( MainBean mainBean ) {
    this.mainBean = mainBean;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    theModel = mainBean.getModel();
    theController = mainBean.getController();
    index = 0L;
    standings = theModel.getStandings();
    horizontalBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel[7];
    updateCharts( standings );
  }

  //
  // queries
  //
  public Integer getCurrYear() {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    return c.get( Calendar.YEAR );
  }

  public void setCurrYear( Integer y ) {
  }

  public void setStandings( List<Standings> standings ) {
    this.standings = standings;
  }

  public List<Standings> getStandings() {
    return standings;
  }

  public Long getIndex() {
    return ++index;
  }

  public List<Byte> getLevels() {
    Byte levels[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    return Arrays.asList( levels );
  }

  public List<Standings> getFilteredStandings() {
    index = 0L;
    return filteredStandings;
  }

  public void setFilteredStandings( List<Standings> filteredStandings ) {
    this.filteredStandings = filteredStandings;
    if( filteredStandings != null )
      this.updateCharts( filteredStandings );
  }

  /*
   * user actions
   */
  public void clickReturn() {
    theController.clickReturn( UI.LIST_STANDINGS );
  }

  public void updateCharts( List<Standings> theList ) {
    for( int chMode = 0; chMode < 7; chMode++ ) {

      HorizontalBarChartModel model = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
      model.setShadow( false );
      model.setZoom( false );
      model.setMouseoverHighlight( false );
//    model.setLegendCols( 4 );
      model.setAnimate( false );
      model.setMouseoverHighlight( true );
      model.setBarMargin( 0 );
      model.setBarPadding( 1 );
//    model.setLegendPlacement( LegendPlacement.OUTSIDE );
//    model.setExtender( "standingsChartExtender" );
//    model.setLegendPosition( "ne" );
      model.setShowPointLabels( true );
      model.setShowDatatip( false );
      model.getAxes()
        .put( AxisType.Y, new CategoryAxis( "Driver Level_Championship" ) );
      Axis xAxis = model.getAxis( AxisType.X );
      xAxis.setLabel( "Points" );
      xAxis.setTickAngle( 0 );

      Collections.reverse( theList );
      ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries();
      //series.setLabel(  );
      for( Standings s : theList ) {
        String dataLabel
               = theModel.getUserFullName(
            s.getId().getUser() )
                 + " L" + s.getId().getLevel()
                 + "_C" + s.getId().getChampionship();
        switch( chMode ) {
          case ChMode.SRD:series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSd() + s.getPointsRd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.SD: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.RD: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsRd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.ED: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsEd() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.SO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsSo() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.RO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsRo() ) );
            break;
          case ChMode.EO: series.set( dataLabel, (int)( s.getPointsEo() ) );
            break;
        }
      }
      if( theList != null && theList.size() > 0 )
        model.addSeries( series );
      Collections.reverse( theList );

      horizontalBarModel[chMode] = model;
    }
  }

  public int getChartHeight() {
    return 60 + 15 * ( filteredStandings == null ? standings.size() : filteredStandings.size() );
  }

  public HorizontalBarChartModel getChartModel( int chMode ) {
    return horizontalBarModel[chMode];
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Functionality Methods
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public String getUserName( long userNumber ) {
    return theModel.getUserFullName( userNumber );
  }

  public String getChampionshipName( Standings item ) {
    return item == null ? "Unknown"
           : theModel
        .getChampionshipName(
          item.getId()
            .getLevel(),
          item.getId()
            .getChampionship()
        );
  }

  public String getLevelName( int level ) {
    String[] levelName = {
      "Planet",
      "Intl. Region",
      "Country",
      "Nat. Region",
      "State",
      "Municipality",
      "Venue",
      "Variant"
    };
    return level + " " + levelName[ level ];

  }

  private static class ChMode {

    public static final int SRD = 0;
    public static final int SD = 1;
    public static final int RD = 2;
    public static final int ED = 3;
    public static final int SO = 4;
    public static final int RO = 5;
    public static final int EO = 6;

    public ChMode() {
    }
  }

  public String getChampionshipsStandingsTitle() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "CHAMPIONSHIPS STANDINGS" );
  }

  public String getRowTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "ROW" );
  }

  public String getYearTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "YEAR" );
  }

  public String getUserTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "USER" );
  }

  public String getLevelTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "LEVEL" );
  }

  public String getChampionshipTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "CHAMPIONSHIP" );
  }

  public String getSR_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "SR DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getS_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "S DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getR_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "R DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getE_DriverPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "E DRIVER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getS_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "S OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getR_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "R OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public String getE_OwnerPointsTxt() {
    return java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( "View/BundleViewSpanish" )
      .getString( "E OWNER POINTS" );
  }

  public void sortEvent( SortEvent e ){
    e.getSortColumn();
  }

  public void filterEvent( FilterEvent e ){
    e.toString();
  }
}
```